# how to stop my ISP from changing my computer DNS setting

Tags: dns, isp

I keep setting my DNS on a Mac to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8 and ATT keeps changing it back to theirs. On my Mac!

How is this possible? and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Isp aint doing it.

Comment: Isp can't change your computer DNS setting.

Comment: Please show how you changed your DNS settings.

Comment: Some AV software or DNS-related software will prevent you from modifying DNS settings. You might check installed software.

Answer (score 2):

The ISP isn't the one changing your DNS.
Although I don't use a Mac, I'm guessing this could happen when you switch networks.
DNS configuration is often saved only for the network you are currently on.

If that's the case, disabling the option to automatically join a known Wi-Fi network on those you aren't using could fix this issue - or at least make it happen only when you manually switch networks.

If your Mac is a desktop computer, you could try directly setting your DNS server in your router's settings, if that option is available for your router.